# Haskell: How does the Data.List.isInfixOf function work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been trying to understand the `isInfixOf` function from the `Data.List` module, to no avail. Here's the code:

```
     isInfixOf               :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
     isInfixOf needle haystack = any (isPrefixOf needle) (tails haystack)

     -- Example:
     --
     -- >isInfixOf "Haskell" "I really like Haskell." -> True
     -- >isInfixOf "Ial" "I really like Haskell." -> False
```

The `any` returns True if at least one item in the list fulfills the condition. It's type is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`

The `isPrefixOf` and the `tails` functions codes are these:

```
    isPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
    isPrefixOf [] _ = True
    isPrefixOf _ [] = False
    isPrefixOf (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && isPrefixOf xs ys

    tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
    tails xs = xs : case xs of 
                    [] -> [] 
                    _  : xs' -> tails xs'

    -- Example: 
    -- tails "abc" == ["abc", "bc", "c",""]
```

I've read about curried functions and partial applied functions but I couldn't understand it yet, neither could I understand how this particular function works. How can it work if `any` takes lists, not a list of lists, as a parameter?

Comment: A list of lists is still a list. That is, the `a` in `any`'s type can be a list type.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen But when I code `any (>5) [[6]]` it returns an error. When I code `any (>5) [6]`, it returns `True`. Also, I was hoping that someone could illuminate me as to how the `isInfixOf` function works, because there must be some Haskell features there that I couldn't understand yet.

Comment: Well in that case you are trying to make `a` be both a list and a *number* at the same time. *That* doesn't work.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks to your insight, I think I got it: `isPrefixOf needle` is a function that will take a list and return a `Bool`, and it's applied to every element in the list returned by `tails haystack`, just like `>5` was applied to `[6]`. Is that it? How can I thank you for your time man?

Comment: (1) Yep. (2) I think you already did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could read `isInfixOf needle haystack = any (isPrefixOf needle) (tails haystack)` as: **return `True` if `needle` `isPrefixOf` `any` subdivision of `haystack` taking away the first elements (i.e., taking the `tails`) of it.**

Isn't it clear yet? Let's try another approach, using your example.

```
isInfixOf "Haskell" "I really like Haskell."
```

Giving that `String` is the same as `[Char]`, we have the following signature for your example:

```
isInfixOf :: (Eq [Char]) => [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
```

So far so good, huh? Let's see `any`? No. Let's see `isPrefixOf`, because it is actually called first and fill the type blanks of `any`.

```
isPrefixOf :: (Eq Char) -> [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
```

So what `isPrefixOf` doing? It is comparing, `Char` by `Char`, if the first `String` (or array of `Char`s) is in the begining of the second `String`. Now, let's get back to `any`: `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. But the function being passed to `any`, in the example, is `isPrefixOf needle`, i.e., `isPrefixOf "Haskell"`. Or, in other words, the function begin passed to `any`, of the type `(a -> Bool)`, is actually `(String -> Bool)` or, if you prefer, `([Char] -> Bool)`. Got it? It is about the partial application functions: `isPrefixOf` is, originally (in our example),

```
isPrefixOf :: (Eq Char) -> [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
```

However, I am passing, as a function, `isPrefixOf "Haskell"`, so it is fixed as `isPrefixOf "Haskell" :: "Haskell" -> [Char] -> Bool`, a notation that doesn't exist as you can imagine. Let's make it "real"? Just take away what seems strange:

```
isPrefixOf "Haskell" :: [Char] -> Bool
```

or

```
isPrefixOf "Haskell" :: String -> Bool
```

Back, again, to `any`. As you can imagine, `any`, now, is

```
any :: (String -> Bool) -> [String] -> Bool
```

or

```
any :: ([Char] -> Bool) -> [[Char]] -> Bool
```

Well, I think that now the idea of `tails` is totally clear for you.

```
tails "I really like Haskell." :: String -> [String]
```

or

```
tails "I really like Haskell." :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
```

At the end, the execution is:

```
isInfixOf "Haskell" "I really like Haskell." = 
any (isPrefixOf "Haskell") (tails "I really like Haskell.") = 
any (isPrefixOf "Haskell") [
    "I really like Haskell.",
    " really like Haskell.",
    "really like Haskell.",
    "eallylike Haskell.",
    "ally like Haskell.",
    "lly like Haskell.",
    "ly like Haskell.",
    "y like Haskell.",
    " like Haskell.",
    "like Haskell.",
    "ike Haskell.",
    "ke Haskell.",
    "e Haskell.",
    "Haskell.",
    "Haskell.",
    "askell.",
    "skell.",
    "kell.",
    "ell.",
    "ll.",
    "l.",
    ".",
    ""]
```

Well, it is easy to very that `"Haskell"` is prefix of `"Haskell."`.

I hope I have explained it clearly. :)